# How to fix AddEmbeddedImage?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I can not see my photos, how to fix this error? (I am running on Task Scheduler)

I changed places of photos

```php
$strhtmlBody = "";
$strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . '<table border="0" width="100%">';
    $strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . "<tr>";
        $strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . '<td valign="middle">';
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('C://tools//Charts//x.png', 'like');
            $strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . '<div><img src="cid:like" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%"></div>';
        $strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . "</td>";
    $strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . "</tr>";
$strhtmlBody = $strhtmlBody . "</table>";
```

Comment: The path with double forward slashes looks wrong … a _forward_ slash does not need escaping in PHP strings.

Comment: @04FS I have problem about cookies. Thank you, I solved.